# SUM OVER PARTITION BY 2 last row same value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum, mariadb

Can anyone explain to me?

My Query :

```
SELECT `Date`,`qtyS`,SUM(`qtyS`) OVER (ORDER BY `Date`)  
FROM  ic_transaction ORDER BY `Date`
```

I got this

```
Date                   qtyS       SUM(qtyS) OVER (ORDER BY `Date`)
2018-06-20 13:11:11    30.0000    30.0000
2018-06-20 14:07:25    10.0000    40.0000
2018-06-20 14:35:45    10.0000    50.0000
2018-06-25 11:19:42   -20.0000    30.0000
2018-06-25 16:49:01   -20.0000    10.0000
2018-06-26 15:52:13    20.0000    30.0000
2018-09-11 21:07:10    10.0000    60.0000
2018-09-11 21:07:10    20.0000    60.0000
```

Why do the last two rows have the same sum?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two rows have the exact same date, so they are considered as equivalent for the sorting. Hence, not only do they have the same cumulative sum, each of their sums includes the value of both these rows.

Comment: So how i can fix my query?

Comment: @Youngzie you could add a secondary sorting criterion, e.g., the `qtyS`